# How do I get HP Advisor to stop coming up?

Tags: hp-pavilion

I've got an HP Pavillion desktop.  I don't want the HP Advisor coming up automatically - how do I stop it from doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laptops are usually filled with manufacturer's software which are mostly unnecessary and bloated. If you don't have any need for this program, you can simply just uninstall it from your computer.

> The HP Advisor Software provides information about the status of the PC along with alerts, updates, and offers from HP.

If however you use HP Advisor for some purpose, have a look if it has any settings you can edit. It's likely that you can disable these notifications you are receiving.

Answer (score 2):

Press the `Windows` button and `R` to open the `Run` window, and type `msconfig`.

On the `Startup` tab, look for 'HP Advisor' in the list.

That, or just uninstall it from the computer.

Comment: If you really want to uninstall it from your computer - *all traces removed*, use Revo Uninstaller- http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html